# Data access error when trying to push and try_pop using concurrent_queue and unique_ptr

Tags: c++

> hello A data access memory access error occurs  when trying to push
> and try_pop using  concurrent_queue and unique_ptr.  How can I solve
> this? please help me I am attaching the problem code below.

```
class CMyData 
{
    public:
        CString strMsg = _T("this is test data");
        // std::string = "this is testdata Also error"
        std::unique_ptr<CMyData> test1()
        {
            return std::make_unique<CMyData>();
        }
        /* this code also error */
        std::shared_ptr<CMyData> test2()
        {

            return std::make_shared<CMyData>();
        }
     };
    ...
    void CDlgThreadTest::OnBnClickedCmbCon()
    {
        CMyData data;
        Concurrency::concurrent_queue<CMyData*> q;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            std::unique_ptr<CMyData> ua3 = data.test1();
            q.push(ua3.get());
            TRACE(" loop cnt is => %d : %s \n", i , ua3.get()->strMsg); --> this code work
        }
        int j = 0;
        while (TRUE)
        {
            CMyData* pdata;
            BOOL bisPop = q.try_pop(pdata);
            if (bisPop)
            {
                TRACE(" pop is success => %d : %s", j++, pdata->strMsg); --> this code error
            }
            else
            {
                TRACE(" pop is end => %d : %s", j++);
                break;
            }
            if (q.empty()) return;
        }
}
```

Comment: `ua3.get()` is a pointer to an object whose lifetime ends at the end of the current iteration (it points to the object owned by `ua3`). Dereferencing the pointer after that iteration has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for answer. i want save smart pointer using thread safe queue and pop another block is it possible ? so i am try below test code

Comment: Concurrency::concurrent_queue<CMyData*> q;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  std::unique_ptr<CMyData> ua3 = std::make_unique<CMyData>();
  CMyData* pdata = ua3.get();
  q.push(std::move(std::move(pdata)));
  TRACE("data1 : %s , %s \n", pdata->strKey, pdata->strMsg);
 }  -> [0] = 0x01ae7c30 {strMsg=<An error occurred while reading the characters in the string.> strKey=<An error occurred while reading the characters in the string.> }

Comment: If you want to save the objects, you need a queue of `std::unique_ptr<CMyData>` and move the `unique_ptr`s into and out of the queue. (It is often a mistake to think of the smart "pointers" as pointers.)

Comment: thank you for your advice but i am little bit confusing 
how can i do it? like this? Concurrency::concurrent_queue<std::unique_ptr<CMyData>> q;
// -> it's define out of block
std::unique_ptr<CMyData> sp = std::make_unique<CMyData>();
q.put(sp);